# How to Stream data from WebAPI method to a JavaScript client

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-web-api, streaming

I have a service method written in ASP.Net WebAPI :http://diningphilospher.azurewebsites.net/api/dining?i=12

and JavaScript client gets the response and visualizes it [here](http://visualizer.azurewebsites.net/)

But the nature of Dining Philosophers problem is I never know when the Dead-lock or starvation will happen. So Instead of having a request/response I would like to stream the data through service method and client side JavaScript read the data I assume JSON asynchronously. Currently several post directs me towards [changing the default buffer limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452871/webapi-request-streaming-support?rq=1) in WebAPI so you get a streaming like behavior.

what other(easy or efficient) ways exist to achieve this above behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return PushStreamContent from ASP.NET Web API and use Server Sent Events (SSE) JavaScript API on the client side. Check out **Push Content** section in Henrik's [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henrikn/archive/2012/04/23/using-cookies-with-asp-net-web-api.aspx). Also, see [Strathweb](http://www.strathweb.com/2012/05/native-html5-push-notifications-with-asp-net-web-api-and-knockout-js/). One thing I'm not sure about the latter implementation is the use of ConcurrentQueue. Henrik's implementation uses ConcurrentDictionary and that allows you to remove the StreamWriter object from the dictionary corresponding to the clients who drop out, which will be difficult to implement using ConcurrentQueue, in my opinion.

Also, Strathweb implementation uses KO. If you don't like to use KO, you don't have to. SSE JavaScript APIs have nothing to do with KO.

BTW, SSE is not supported in IE 9 or lesser.

Another thing to consider is the scale out option. Load balancing will be problematic, in the sense there is a chance that the load will not be uniformly distributed, since clients are tied to the server (or web role) they hit first.