# How do I access the request body as a stream, without waiting for the entire body?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a Web API action that accepts large (100 MB+) files and forwards them to another HTTP service. I want to stream the request body to the other service, to prevent having to wait for the entire request body to be pulled into memory.

I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452871/webapi-request-streaming-support) question, which explains how to prevent Web API from buffering the request body, but I can't figure out how to access the stream from the `Request` object in my action.

I've looked at the functions provided by the `HttpContent` class, but they all imply that they pull the entire request into memory.

How can I obtain my request stream without pulling the entire body into memory?

Comment: And what about `Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync()`?

Comment: @Evk According to the .NET Core source, it reads the request into a buffer and wraps it in a `MemoryStream`

Comment: But you didn't mention .net core in question? I usually just read `Request.Body` in asp.net core.

Comment: @Evk .NET 4.5 does the exact same thing. Regadless, per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpcontent.readasstreamasync(v=vs.110).aspx: The returned Task<TResult> object **will complete after all of the stream that represents content has been read**.